# Simple (?) Unix Grep Command

Tags: command-line, unix, grep

How do I recursively view a list of files that has one string and specifically doesn't have another string? Also, I mean looking inside the files, rather than the file names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use find:

```
find . -type f -name "$fileglob" -exec grep -q $word1 {} \; -not -exec grep -q $word2 {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really do want a string, not a regexp, thus `fgrep`, then:

```
fgrep -rl --null desired_string . | xargs -0 fgrep -lv undesired_string --
```

Recursively (`-r`) grep for `desired_string` under the current directory, printing the filenames (`-l`) and using the filenames from that, repeatedly invoke fgrep (so as to not overfill the space for command-line arguments when invoking it), with `-v` inverting the sense of the match.

This uses `--null` to use an ASCII NUL character after each filename, instead of a newline, so that you can handle filenames with spaces in and the like; that plumbs into the `-0` given to xargs. Depending upon the Unix variant (Linux, BSD, etc) there might be a short option for `--null`, but that's less portable. Strictly speaking, `--null` is not portable, but any modern system's (f)grep should have it.

The `--` at the end of the second (f)grep stops (f)grep from looking for options in any following parameters, so even if you have a filename starting with a `-`, it will still be processed as a filename.